# Create mouse events for clicking images in html5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events

I'm new to Javascript and I'm using HTML5 canvas in the Dreamweaver editor. I have looked at other posts about mouse events but none seems to tackle my problem.

I am creating a game called 'Click Only Corn bubbles' where items fall and the player moves the mouse to click the corn bubbles but if they click anything else its game over.

So far I have used:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",eventKeyDown,false);  
window.addEventListener("keyup",eventKeyUp,false);  
window.addEventListener("mousedown",onDown,false);  
window.addEventListener("mouseup",onUp,false);  
window.addEventListener("mousemove",onMove,false);
```

How do I call these so that they are true? Also how do I make them clickable so I am able to click on the images as they fall?

Comment: Almost everyone sees to sat that 'The click event is raised when the user clicks on an element. The click event will occur after the mousedown and mouseup events' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this would be helful.

```
 document.addEventListener('click',mouseClick,false);
 function mouseClick(e)
 {  
   mouseX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
   mouseY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
   //Now mouseX and mouseY contains the x and y location of mouse click event but w.r.t. your canvas location .
 }
```

Comment: Cheers! I think i understand this way better

Comment: sure :) im not sure how though? i just started as a new member

Comment: On the left side of my answer you can see a big '0', take your cursor to upper tick of '0',, you will see a tooltip message saying ("The answer  is useful")just click on it and thats it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to find somehow where the mouse cursor is located. Here is a function to get the mouse coordinates:

```
function getMousePosition(e) {
    var x, y;        

    x = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft - canvas.offsetLeft;
    y = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop - canvas.offsetTop;

    return {
        get x() { return x },
        get y() { return y }
    }
}

HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getMousePosition = getMousePosition;
```

Then we need to test if the mouse has been clicked and if yes locate the mouse and the images coordinates. If the mouse coordinate is overlapping the image coordinate then do something. We can test the condition like in the following method:

```
var isMouseDown = false;
function onDown(e) {
    var pos = {x:0, y:0 };
    isMouseDown = true;
    var mouseCoordinate = getMousePosition(e);
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var bubble = images[i];
        if (( mouseCoordinate.x > image.x && // get the image most left position 
            mouseCoordinate.x < image.x + image.size) && // get image most right position
            ( mouseCoordinate.y > image.y &&
                mouseCoordinate.y < image.y + image.size)) {
            index = image.indexOf(image, 0);
            pos.x = mouseCoordinate.x;
            pos.y = mouseCoordinate.y;
            break;
        }
    }
}


if (isMouseDown &&
    pos.x < image[index].x + image[index].size &&
    pos.x > image[index].x &&
    pos.y < image[index].y + image[index].size &&
    pos.y > image[index].y)
// if the condition is true, then do something        

function onUp(e) {
    isMouseDown = false;
}
```

You can see the live example here: http://hellopixel.net/experiments/404/404.html

Comment: Thank you @esimov! thats exactly what my tutor had suggested i just wasnt sure how to register everything. Do i put all this code anywhere specific in the HTML